# Facebook SDK for iOs isn't working correctly

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios5, sharing

I'm developing an iOs 5 app and I'm trying to add Facebook sharing with Facebook SDK. I've been coding a lot but it doesn't work. This is the code I use from the Facebook Developers Site:

```
- (IBAction) buttonpressed {
    facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"245697495524266" andDelegate:self];

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]) {
        facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
        facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    }
    if (![facebook isSessionValid]) {
        [facebook authorize:nil];
    } else {
        [self fbDidLogin];            
    }          
}            
- (BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    return [facebook handleOpenURL:url]; 
}
- (void)fbDidLogin {
    NSLog(@"Facebook did login");

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:[facebook accessToken] forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    [defaults setObject:[facebook expirationDate] forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    [defaults synchronize];
    // Here I would like to share something (photo...) 
}
```

When I press the button I go to the Facebook app and I have to allow the app, then I return to my app. The problem is that `- (void) fbDidLogin` doesn't run (the `NSLog` doesn't appear in the console), so I can't share anything. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The only problem can be if your class does not conform to `FBSessionDelegate` in its .h file

i.e

```
@interface Yourclass : NSObject <FBSessionDelegate>
```

Comment: I have this <ADBannerViewDelegate, FBLoginDialogDelegate, FBLoginDialogDelegate, FBRequestDelegate, FBSessionDelegate>
So I don't think the problem is that. Or I only have to have the FBSessionDelegate?

Answer (score 0):

Where did you put this code ? in the app delegate?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
 sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation 
{
   return [facebook handleOpenURL:url]; 
}
```

it must be in the app delegate not in your class.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot about this two methods and perhaps forgot to add your Facebook app id to URL types in info file. [for more detail](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/)
 
// Pre 4.2 support

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
    return [facebook handleOpenURL:url]; 
}
```

// For 4.2+ support

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
    sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    return [facebook handleOpenURL:url]; 
}
```